# Where the data in sqlight stored internally

Tags: android, sqlite

I was doing a android project in eclips using sqllight. Can anybody tell me  Where actually the data in sqlight stored internally ? .

Comment: It's not stored in the project, its stored in the actual install directory on your device. I can't be more specific since I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the path to a database on the device by using [Context.getDatabasePath(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29)

In general it will be found at `/data/data/<your_package_name>/databases` but don't rely on that absolute path as it may change in future Android versions.